# React - Using ternary to apply CSS class in functional component

Tags: css, reactjs, classname, ternary, react-props

I'm relatively new to React and working on a John Conway - Game of Life app. I have built a `Gameboard.js` functional component for the board itself (which is a child of `App.js`) and a `Square.js` functional component which represents an individual square in the board (and is a child of `Gameboard` and a grandchild of `App`).

In `App` I have a function called `alive` which I want to change the color of an individual square when it is clicked by the user. `App` also has an 'alive' property in it's state set to false initially and `alive` will change the property to true when called.

Here is `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import GameBoard from './GameBoard.js';
import Controls from './Controls.js';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          boardHeight: 50,
          boardWidth: 30,
          iterations: 10,
          reset: false,
          alive: false
        };
      }

      selectBoardSize = (width, height) => {
        this.setState({
          boardHeight: height,
          boardWidth: width
        });
      }

      onReset = () => {

      }

      alive = () => {
        this.setState({ alive: !this.state.alive });
        console.log('Alive function has been called');

      }



      render() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <h1>Conway's Game of Life</h1>

          <GameBoard
            height={this.state.boardHeight}
            width={this.state.boardWidth}
            alive={this.alive}
          />

            <Controls
              selectBoardSize={this.selectBoardSize}
              iterations={this.state.iterations}
              onReset={this.onReset}
            />

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

`Gameboard` looks like this and passes props.alive to `Square`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Square from './Square.js';

const GameBoard = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="game-board">
          <tbody>
            {Array(props.height).fill(1).map((el, i) => {
              return (
                <tr key={i}>
                  {Array(props.width).fill(1).map((el, j) => {
                    return (
                      <Square key={j} alive={props.alive}/>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
    );
}

export default GameBoard;
```

In my CSS I have a class called active that changes the color of an individual square if it is clicked on. How can I make it so that in `Square` if a td element is clicked the color changes (i.e. the CSS classes is changed to active)?

I've tried this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Square = (props) => {

  return(
    <td className={props.alive ? "active" : "inactive"} onClick={() => props.alive()}></td>
  );
}

export default Square;
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.Square {
  background-color: #013243; //#24252a;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  border: .1px solid rgba(236, 236, 236, .5);
  overflow: none;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #48dbfb; //#00e640; //#2ecc71; //#39FF14;
  }
}

.inactive {
  background-color: #013243; //#24252a;
}

.active {
  background-color:  #48dbfb;
}
```

How can I make it so the .Square CSS class is ALWAYS applied to every square but the individual square color is changed if it's active? In other words, can I set `Square`'s td to always be styled with the .Square CSS class and then individual elements within `Square` can be colored appropriately depending on whether or not `alive` is true in `App`'s state?

Is there are ternary approach to always set one particular CSS class and then, in addition, set 1 of 2 other classes....i.e. the Square CSS class is always shown and active or inactive is rendered depending on logic/state?

Comment: Doesn't work, JSX error. Is my approach here just totally wrong? I feel like there should be a common way to do something like this relatively easily.

Comment: so sorry. I messed up . It should be like className={'Square ${props.alive ? "active" : "inactive"}'} - use backticks instead of single-quote

Comment: No error anymore but the .Square CSS class isn't being applied/the board isn't visible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments have the right idea.

You could use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and embed ternary conditionals in that:

```
return (
    <td
      className={`Square ${props.alive ? "active" : "inactive"}`}
      onClick={() => props.alive()}
    ></td>
);
```

A quick refesher on template literals: use backticks to wrap a string, and you can insert a JavaScript expression inside of that by wrapping it in the `${}` pattern. As a bonus, template literals can span multiple lines, so no more awkward string concatenation!

```
const myName = "Abraham Lincoln";
const myString = `Some text.
  This text is on the next line but still in the literal.
  Newlines are just fine.
  Hello, my name is ${myName}.`;
```

**Edit**: The bigger problem that I see now is that you're not storing the state of each your cells anywhere. You have only a single boolean stored in `App` called `alive`... what you really need is an *array* of booleans, with each boolean representing the state of a single `Square`.

The array of "alive" states should live in the `App` or `GameBoard`, following the React principle of ["the data flows down"](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down). In your case you could try keeping it in `App`, and that way `GameBoard` and `Square` can remain purely functional components.

Inside of `App` you could create a new 2-dimensional array, `board`, in the constructor and fill it with sub-arrays of `0` values initially:

```
// App.js
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      boardHeight: 50,
      boardWidth: 30,
      board: [],
      iterations: 10,
      reset: false,
    };

    this.state.board = new Array(this.state.boardHeight).fill(new Array(this.state.boardWidth).fill(0));
  }
```

In the `board` array, each index represents one row. So a simplified example of `[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]` would represent:

```
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 1 1
```

`GameBoard` should render your grid of cells based purely on the `board` prop passed to it, and pass each `Square` its alive value and callback function as props:

```
const GameBoard = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="game-board">
          <tbody>
            {this.props.board.map((row, y) => {
              return <tr key={y}>
                {row.map((ea, x) => {
                  return (
                    <Square
                      key={x}
                      x={x}
                      y={y}
                      isAlive={ea}
                      aliveCallback={this.props.alive}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </tr>;
            })}
          </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
    );
}
```

From there you should be able to see how this app would work. `App` stores the game state and renders the functional component `GameBoard`. In `GameBoard`, each `Square` renders according to its alive value, and triggers an `aliveCallback` when clicked. `aliveCallback` should set the state of the appropriate value in the `board` array inside of `App`, based on its `x` and `y` prop.

Comment: The template literal compiles and applies the active class, but the entire board is changed to the active color instead of just individual squares that have been clicked. I want clicked squares to apply .active and all the other squares to stay colored the way they were.

Comment: Would I be better off changing `Square.js` to a class component and storing whether each square is active within the component instead of passing it as props?

Comment: @NickKinlen Updated my answer with more detail. :)

Comment: Thanks. This is good advice. I knew the approach I was taking would not be the final approach, but I was just focused on getting the click functionality working. This advice definitely clears up the next question I had.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
return(
    <td className={`Square ${props.alive ? "active" : "inactive"}`} 
       onClick={() => props.alive()}>
    </td>
  );
```

Please refer this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/5x17l2zwnk)

Comment: This changes every square on the board to active or inactive. I want only the squares that are active to apply to active color and for the rest of the squares to apply the inactive color.

Comment: use this className attribute in your Square component and pass it props as alive. Then it will only affect that component.

Comment: I was unable to format my answer so used <backtick> instead of `. Although I have shared the working link of my code. Shouldnt be any problem there

Answer (score 0):

**Problem from title was not a real reason of 'not working'**

**NOTE: This statement**

> className={props.alive ? "active" : "inactive"}

**is correct**, using template literals isn't required.

You can write/use it in many ways:

```
className={'Square '+ (props.alive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
```

To be true there is no need to use 'inactive' as 'Square' has the same bg color.

```
className={'Square '+ (props.alive ? 'active' : null)}
```

and de facto no need for ternary operator

```
className={'square '+ (props.alive && 'active')}
```

and of course you can 'calculate/prepare' values in plain js before return

```
const Square = (props) => {
  let classes = ['Square','bb']
  if( props.alive ) classes.push('active')
  classes = classes.join(' ')
  return (
    <h1 className={classes}>Hello</h1>
  )};
```

**Just read [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) or google for 'react css in js'.**