# React - Game of Life - Update state of specific elements in 2D array depending on which elements are clicked by user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, immutability, setstate

I'm still learning React and working on coding John Conway's Game of Life. I have created a game board for the game using a 2D array in state. I have this 2D array stored in state in my `App.js`. I also have two functional components, `Gameboard.js` and `Square.js` receiving props and creating the game board.

`Gameboard.js` creates a table and passed props to `Square.js` letting it know which squares should be highlighted and which shouldn't. In other words it let's each individual square know if the user has clicked it and if it's "alive" in the Game of Life sense.

After a user clicks a specific square in `Square.js` I have a callback function triggered onClick. The callback function, `aliveCallback`, passes the X and Y coordinates of the specific square that was clicked back to `App.js`. `App.js` triggers a function called `alive`.

When `alive` is called I need to update the state of the 2D array so that the specific square (it's X and Y coordinates, for example [0, 0] or [0, 1] etc...) is set to the boolean stored in state. Then, this boolean can be passed to `Gameboard.js` as `isAlive`. The game board then passes that `isAlive` value to `Square.js` and `Square.js` has conditional rendering that tells that individual square to be highlighted light blue.

This has been a mouth full and it would probably be easiest to [check out the Codesandbox and see the structure of the project](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Nicknyr/FCC_Game_Of_Life). It also helps to mention that I am following advice a SO poster gave me in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413319/react-using-ternary-to-apply-css-class-in-functional-component).

After doing some reading and looking at the React docs it appears a good approach to this issue is to use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) and it's `update` function. That's the approach I have taken but I can't seem to properly update the state of the specific square clicked using it's X and Y coordinates.

Instead of posting code here it would probably just be easier and neater to check out the code on CodeSandbox. How can I write my `alive` function so that it properly updates the state of whatever square is clicked on?

Here is what I've tried:

```
alive = (x, y) => {
    console.log(x, y);

    const data = this.state.board;
    const ySquare = y;
    const xSquare = x;
    console.log("X square is : " + xSquare);
    console.log("Y square is : " + ySquare);

    const updateData = update(data, {
      xSquare: {$set: this.setState({ alive: !this.state.alive })}
    });

  }
```

The logic here is to try to pass xSquare and ySquare to `update` and then try to set alive to true for that particular square.

Comment: Why not taking inspiration from some [ready projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38586114/game-of-life-in-react-redux-help-in-increasing-performance?rq=1)?? Why adding new complications (immutability) while earlier problem not resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have a state variable `alive` on the App which is being confused for the life status of each cell.

I've reworked things a bit, and my solution does not use `update from 'immutability-helper'` since I'm not familiar with it, but the logic in my solution is pretty straightforward I think.

Here is `App.alive`:

```
alive = (x, y) => {
  console.log(x, y);

  const data = this.state.board;
  const ySquare = y;
  const xSquare = x;
  console.log("X square is : " + xSquare);
  console.log("Y square is : " + ySquare);

  const newData = data.map((row, y) => {
    return y === ySquare ? (
      row.map((cell, x) => x === xSquare ? 1 : cell)
    ) : (
      row
    )
  })

  this.setState({ board: newData });
}
```

Basically `newData` comes from going over each cell in the board and if the current cell's coordinates match `xSquare, ySquare` it sets the value of the cell to `1`, otherwise it leaves it unchanged.

As an additional note, I'd recommend renaming this method to something like `makeCellAlive` just to be more clear that it is a method that does something.

**Edit**:

If you wanted to have click either make the cell alive or dead depending on it's current state, you could change the line:

```
row.map((cell, x) => x === xSquare ? 1 : cell)
```

to

```
row.map((cell, x) => x === xSquare ? (cell + 1) % 2 : cell)
```

Looks like a cool app btw.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was massively overthinking this one.