# Copying two-dimensional array from state in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to build a small react app to model [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). I've set up a two-dimensional array to track the state of each cell in a 10-by-10 grid.

I'm attempting to store this array in the State. At each "tick" of the game, I want to make a copy of the array, evaluate each cell, potentially giving it a new value, and then assign the copy back to state. I'm basing this off of the official [React Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) where they use this exact approach:

```
handleClick(i) {
    //Make a copy from state
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    //Make some changes to it
    squares[i] = 'X';
    //Set state to the new value
    this.setState({squares: squares});
}
```

My initial approach was to use `slice()` as in the example above. Through debugging, I discovered that this didn't work; somehow state is being changed even though I have used various methods to copy it that shouldn't make changes to it. (I understand that if I say `var x = this.state.blah` and `x = 5` that I have changed state because `blah` is a reference to it)

Here is my code:

```
doTick = () => {
    console.log("doin a tick");
    console.log(this.state.squares);
    //None of these approaches works
    //Three different copy strategies all fail
    //const newSquares = Object.assign({}, this.state.squares);
    //const newSquares = [...this.state.squares];
    //const newSquares = this.state.squares.slice();
    const newSquares = this.state.squares.slice();
    const origSquares = [...this.state.squares];
    //Iterating over the array
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        newSquares[i][j] = evaluateCell(origSquares[i][j], this.countLiveNeighbors(i, j, origSquares));
        //evaluateCell(origSquares[i][j], this.countLiveNeighborsAndLog(i, j, origSquares));
      }
    }

    //this.setState({
      //squares: newSquares
    //});
  }
```

Even though the `setState()` call is commented out, just having the assignment of `newSquares[i][j] = //...` is enough to somehow modify state.

Here's the code where I set up the initial array in the constructor for the Board component:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var array = new Array(10);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      array[i] = new Array(10).fill(false);
    }
    this.state = {
      squares: array
    };
    console.log(this.state.squares);
  }
```

I took a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449949/react-game-of-life-update-state-of-specific-elements-in-2d-array-depending-o) but I'm not having any trouble updating the squares based on clicks (that part of my code works fine). Various SO posts and in-person troubleshooters suggested the three different copy strategies that all produce the same problem. I also took a look [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5).

I'm very new to React and not very skilled in JS generally, and obviously I don't have a good handle on State. Here are my questions:

1. How can I make a copy of state/part of state/data in state in such a way that the copy is not a reference to state? I want to be able to change this new data without changing state (until I am ready).
2. Why are the methods used above NOT working properly? The documentation for slice() assures me that I'm getting a copy and not a reference.

Thanks in advance! I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) only does a **shallow** copy of the values. This means if you have any nested values in them, they will be referenced rather than copied. For instance:

```js
const a = { field: { innerField: 'test' } };
const b = { ...a } // b ===  { field: { innerField: 'test' } } SAME field as a
```

To copy a nested array you should use deep copy methods, such as [Lodash's cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) or [Ramda's clone](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#clone)

for example, with Lodash's cloneDeep:

```js
const newSquares = _.cloneDeep(this.state.squares);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did encounter Lodash's cloneDeep in my research as well. Two questions:

1. Why does `slice()` not work? The documentation says that it returns a copy of the values, not a reference.
2. Is there really no simple/easy way in regular JS to create a deep copy? It really boggles the mind that you would need to import some external library to perform what seems like a basic task.

Comment: `slice()` does the same as `...` - shallow copy. Unfortunately I don't know any built-in way of doing so.